# primeNg Checkbox binding object in Datatable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, primeng

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox

In the below code I am trying to get the checkboxes to add objects to an array that is in model driven form with the variable name of selectedComponents.

So the object type of item1 below is  CampaignProductModel and that is an array called selectedComponents in my model for the form.

I am having trouble binding and added of all checked items to the array in my model object.

```
 <p-dataTable *ngIf="perviousCampaignProduct" [value]="perviousCampaignProduct" #dt [responsive]="true" filter="filter" [rows]="25" [paginator]="true" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedItem" [contextMenu]="cm">
    <p-header>Pervious Campaign Products </p-header>
    <p-column header="Images">
        <template let-item="rowData" pTemplate="body">
          <img style="max-height:150px;" src="http://cdnll.somesite.com/images/1000/{{item.itemSku}}.jpg" />
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="itemSku" header="Item" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" filterPlaceholder="Search"></p-column>
    <p-column field="components" header="Components">
       <template let-item="rowData" let-col pTemplate="body">
          <ul style="list-style: none;">
             <li *ngFor="let item1 of item[col.field]">
                <p-checkbox value="item1" formControlName="selectedComponents" label="{{item1.itemSku}}"></p-checkbox>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </template>
     </p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```

**Goal**

Added all check items from p-checkbox as objects to an array in my model driven form.

Tried:

```
value="{{item1}}"
```

... knew it won't work

Answer (score 2):

It´s a bit later but i think this can resolve your problem
Change this code:

```
 <p-checkbox value="item1" formControlName="selectedComponents" label="{{item1.itemSku}}"></p-checkbox>
```

for this one:

```
 <p-checkbox [value]="item1" formControlName="selectedComponents" [label]="item1.itemSku"></p-checkbox>
```